# Get date when forecast target value will be reached

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I have a Google spreadsheet (but it will apply to Excel as well, hence the tag for others to find this) with the following conditions:

column A: dates
column B: decimal values (going up and down, but decreasing over time)
[some other columns]
column H: `FORECAST()` for the B value depending on past A and B values

In a cell on another sheet, I enter a target value that I want B on the first sheet to reach. I also want to display the date when the forecast reaches the target value for the first time.

How can I get the date with a formula? (If it is possible at all - or do I need scripting?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that works for me:

```
=MIN(FILTER(A2:A; ISNUMBER(H2:H); H2:H<=80; B2:B<=80))
```

where 80 is the target value (that will come from the second sheet in my case).

I will wait before I accept my own answer in case someone comes up with a better solution or points out that something's not right with mine.